# Same controller listed with different "Setting ID" in x360CE doesn't work

Tags: controllers, x360ce

This one doesn't work:

[image]

This one does:

[image]

As far as I can tell, the only difference is the "Setting ID". Removing and re-adding the controller creates another one with 0BEDCE40 that doesn't work.

Games that have the 21993449 version can use the controller fine. One, Remnant: From the Ashes, worked last night. But when I tried to use the controller with a wire because the battery was dead, obviously it didn't work since it's a different device and hadn't been added to X360CE, so I tried adding it and it failed to function. Then I deleted both devices from its setting, and now when I add back the wireless adaptor I get 0BEDCE40 and it doesn't work.

So my guess is if I remove the controller and re-add it to Rocket League (which currently works) it will stop working.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the "Direct Input " tab, you can copy/paste presets from one that works to one that doesn't. Doing this changes the Setting ID to the one that was working.

So it was just these mappings that weren't updated properly.

[image]